# Where can i find jpa orm.xml usage samples

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I am trying to see some usage samples of JPA orm.xml. If some one direct me to a link,

Answer (score 8):

The schema is here,

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd

There are lots of samples of each mapping type here,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence

Lots of examples here,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA

In particular,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EmployeeXML

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete answer but, http://www.jpox.org/docs/1_2/tutorials/jpa_tutorial.html uses JPA 1.0.  However, it was of use when I created my ORM.xml for JPA 2.0.  I know "Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0" from O'Reilly has good examples too.  Otherwise you have to look at the schema (would post the link but apparently I don't have enough rep to post multiple links) and match it up with annotations examples...at least that is what I had to do.

ORM.xml appears to be falling out of favor for the annotation version, which explains the difficulty of finding any good examples of ORM.xml file.

Comment: As a friend of mine pointed out, with all the annotations now ending up on a model/domain object, sometimes using XML just increases sanity, so I think there are reasons you might want to use XML.

Comment: It also appears the link is broken.